# LINQ Select mutiply columns as data source for combobox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, combobox

I have a combobox that must contain list of clients  from(Client table) that own estate(Estate table). Both tables contains ClientID fields. I want to get ClientID from Estate table as a ValueMember and Client Name from Client table as a DisplayMember of combobox like this:

```
        ClientComboBox.DataSource = ownerQuery;
        ClientComboBox.DisplayMember = "ClientName";
        ClientComboBox.ValueMember = "ClientID";
```

I have a query that gives me only ClientName:

```
 var ownerQuery = (from own in AgencyContext.Client
            join clName in AgencyContext.Estate on own.ClientID equals clName.ClientID
            select own.ClientName);
```

How can I get ClientID and ClientName form one query as source for Combobox.

Comment: Change ' select own.ClientName ' to ' select own ' at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var ownerQuery = (from own in AgencyContext.Client
            join clName in AgencyContext.Estate on own.ClientID equals clName.ClientID
            select own.ClientName);
```

To:

```
var ownerQuery = (from own in AgencyContext.Client
            join clName in AgencyContext.Estate on own.ClientID equals clName.ClientID
            select own);
```

Answer (score 1):

With an anonymous type:

```
 var qry = (from client in AgencyContext.Client
            join estate in AgencyContext.Estate on client.ClientID equals estate.ClientID
            select new 
            {
                ClientId = estate.ClientId,
                ClientName = client.ClientName
            });
```

which you can use like so:

```
    ClientComboBox.DataSource = qry;
    ClientComboBox.DisplayMember = qry.First().ClientName;
    ClientComboBox.ValueMember = qry.First().ClientId;
```